# Convert integer A to integer B using three operations any number of time

Tags: c++

> You are given a, b and c. You need to convert a to b. You can perform following operations:
>
> 1. Multiply a by c
> 2. Decrease a by 2
> 3. Decrease a by 1
>    You can perform this operation in any order and any number of times.
>    You need to find and print minimum number of steps to convert a to b.
>
> Constraints:
> 1 ≤ t ≤10^4
> 0 ≤ a, b, c ≤10^9
>
> Input:
> First line contains number of test cases. Next t line for contains three space separated integer a, b, c.
>
> Output:
> Print minimum no. of steps as output in new line for each test case.
>
> SAMPLE INPUT
> 2
> 3 10 2
> 11 6 2
>
> SAMPLE OUTPUT
> 3
> 3
>
> For test case 1:
>
> 1. First multiply 3 with 2.
> 2. Subtract 1 from  6 to get 5.
> 3. Multiple 5 with  2  to get  10.
>    So, 3 steps.
>
> For test case 2:
>
> 1. Subtract 2 from 11.
> 2. Subtract 2 from 9.
> 3. Subtract 1 from 7.
>    So, 3 steps.

My code is taking more time than expected, my solution is O(n) solution.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

int minimumSteps(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (a == b || (a < b && c <= 1)) return 0;
    unordered_set<int> visited{a};
    queue<int> q;
    q.push(a);

    int count = 0;
    int answer = INT_MAX;
    int result = 0;
    while (!q.empty()) {
        int n = q.size();
        while (n--) {
            int current = q.front();
            cout << current << " ";
            q.pop();

            result = current * c;
            if (result == b) return min(count + 1, answer);
            if (current < b && !visited.count(result)) { 
                if (result < b) {
                    q.push(result);
                    visited.insert(result); 
                } else answer = min(answer, count + ((result - b) / 2) + ((result - b) % 2) + 1);
            } 

            int subtract[2] = { current - 2, current - 1 };
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                result = subtract[i];
                if (result == b) return min(count + 1, answer);
                if (result > 0 && !visited.count(result)) {
                    q.push(result);
                    visited.insert(result); 
                }
            } 
        }
        count++;
    }

    return min(answer, count);
}

int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;

    while (t--) {
        int a, b, c;
        cin >> a >> b >> c;

        int result = minimumSteps(a, b, c);
        cout << "Ans: " << result << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `n` in your `O(n)` claim? What brought you to the conclusion about the complexity?

Comment: What is your actual question? If your code works, and you just want to optimize it, you should ask on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. However, if your question is about an actual problem that you are trying to fix, then you should [edit] your question explain that better. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the time complexity is actually O(b) as in the worst case I am visiting each number from 1 to b to reach b. I want to optimize the code as it is taking too much time for input like a=1, b=1000000000 and c= 2.

Comment: the trick is to realize that you do not have to carry out the steps when you only need the number of steps required as answer. Its not so much about tweaking your current code, but about doing the maths and finding the trick to avoid the brute force

Comment: @Om Londhe, your solution is not O(n) or O(b) - on every iteration you are increasing your count of candidates by a factor of nearly 3. (Not quite three because (x-1)-2 = (x-2)-1.) If b < a the answer is obvious and O(1) because minimum operations would inevitably require you to do it by repeated subtractions (see the second example). Search for something analogous for b > a. Note that your first example could actually be done in a different way ... with the same final number of operations ... Finally, your specification allows c to be 0, in which case you can't get from a=1 to b=2.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of tricks you can employ here, but the important things to realize are:

1. You don't need to actually find all the operations in order to count them -- you can do your search with "retroactively" inserting operations before the last operation.
2. You have one operation that increases the size, and for the operations that decrease the size, it will never be worth going from *b+1* to *b-1* with the decrease 2, as the decrease 1 would get you to *b* (and finish) in that case.

Combining those two, you can see that after multiplying by *c*, it is possible to reduce by *c* or by *2c* by "retroactively" doing a *-1* or *-2* before the **c*.  So the process becomes, starting from *a* figure out how many times you need to mulitply by *c* to get to *>= b*, then figure out how many additional subtractions (of the various multiples of powers of c that are possible) to get down to b.

So you get something like:

```
int minSteps(int a, int b, int c) {
    assert(c > 1);  // c values less than 2 make no sense
    int cton = 1;  // c to the n power, where n is the number of multiplies
    int count = 0;
    std::vector<int> subs = { 1, 2 };  // possible subtracts
    while (a < b) {
        cton *= c;
        a *= c;
        ++count;
        if (subs.back() != cton) subs.push_back(cton);
        subs.push_back(2*cton); }
    while (a > b) {
        while (subs.back() > a - b) subs.pop_back();
        assert(!subs.empty());
        a -= subs.back();
        count++; }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a > b then the fastest route is by multiple subtractions, subtracting 2 as many times as possible and then a single subtraction of 1 if necessary.

If a < b you have to get up to b as fast as possible. Consider the LAST step. If b is a multiple of c then recurse on b / c. If b is not a multiple of c then you will have to approach it (via subtractions) from the next multiple above.

There are special cases: a == b (whence no operations), a < b and c <= 1 (not possible).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int minimumSteps( int a, int b, int c )
{
   if ( a == b ) return 0;                                 // case trivial - no ops needed
   if ( a < b && c <= 1 ) return -1;                       // case impossible - flag with -1
   if ( a > b ) return ( a - b ) / 2 + ( a - b ) % 2;      // case downward: fastest route by repeated subtraction

   // Left with a < b
   int bmodc = b % c;
   if ( bmodc == 0 )                                       // if b is divisible by c get to it from below ...
   {
      return 1 + minimumSteps( a, b / c, c );              // ... recursively
   }
   else
   {
      int toBeAdded = c - bmodc;                           // if not, get to it from the next multiple of c above
      return toBeAdded / 2 + toBeAdded % 2 + 1 + minimumSteps( a, b / c + 1, c );
   }
}

int main()
{
   int a, b, c;
   cout << "Enter a, b, c: ";   cin >> a >> b >> c;
   cout << "Minimum steps = " << minimumSteps( a, b, c ) << "\n";
}
```